# Can a C# dictionary have two different types(normal object and list of objects) of values?

Tags: c#, .net

Code:-

```
public Dictionary<string, List<TestObj>> testDictionary = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<TestObj>>();  

if (!testDictionary.ContainsKey(testObjId))  
{
     TestObj testObj=new TestObj(testObjId);
     List<VID> testObjList= new List<TestObj>  
     {
         testObj  
     };  
     testDictionary.Add(testObjId, testObjList);  
}  
else  
{  
    testDictionary[testObjId].Add(new TestObj(testObjId));  
}
```

Scenario:-

1. Most of the cases there will be only one entry in the list,which is waste of resource.
2. In special scenario we would have multiple items in the list.

Need help in handling the scenario where in if we have only one item then the value of the dictionary must be normal object if we have multiple items then value of the dictionary must be list of items.

Comment: You could use `IList<TestObj>` as value type. Then implement a version of `IList` that is optimized for a single entry (like internally holding only one instance instead of an array). Then, add to your dictionary either a "real" List<> or your own type.

Comment: Put everything in a list and handle the case where the count is 1? Go for meeting the requirements and correctness before you jump into optimizing it for speed/memory.

Comment: Is the `TestObj` reference type or value type? Or it can be either?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias,TestObj is a value type.

Comment: Could you make an estimation for these two metrics? 1. Percent of keys holding a single value, and 2. average number of values for the keys that hold multiple values.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias,90% of time it holds single value.